# Calling git from PHP: Broken pipe error

Tags: php, git, broken-pipe

I have the following PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo shell_exec(
  "/usr/bin/git clone --bare ".
  "/home/dave/create_project/template_project ".
  "/home/dave/create_project/my_test_project.git"
);
```

About 7 in 10 times that I run it, git gives the following error:

```
find: write error: Broken pipe
```

This error never occurs if I run the equivalent command directly from the shell.

I have already tried:

- using other PHP execution functions: `exec`, `system`, `popen`;
- passing the whole command as an argument to bash, i.e., `exec('bash -c '.$cmd);`

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your exact platform, but [findutils has been known](http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=184761) to throw that kind of error message before.
On Fedora, that [rpm package version 4.2.33-2.fc9](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=44144) fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Ubuntu Hardy so the linked issue doesn't directly apply.

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP throw any errors? Maybe max_execution_time is too low? Mu guess PHP app exites prematurely.

Comment: No, PHP doesn't throw any errors and I can put code after the shell_exec call and it gets executed so I don't think it's timing out.